# Laravel console table with column width

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have just discovered the table rendering function in [Laravel console command](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#tables).
My project is built on Laravel 5.8, but even if there is an answer for more advanced versions it will be great to know.

I am looking for rendering a table with determined (or even better - limitted) column width. Something like:

```
$data = [
    ['John', 'The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Night-Time'],
    ['Rachel', 'The Catcher in the Rye']
];

// Code for columns width is missing
$this->table(['Name', 'Favorite book'], $data);
```

So the output will be:

```
+--------+-------------------------+
| Name   | Favorite book           |
+--------+-------------------------+
| John   | The Curious Incident... |
| Rachel | The Catcher in the Rye  |
+--------+-------------------------+
```

I saw that [Symfony table](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/table.html) (which laravel table is based on) has a `setColumnWidths()` function, but I cannot find any way to use it from the console command.

Does somebody know if it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot use `setColumnWidths`, because the `table` only supports table style and column style, as you can [see here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Console/Concerns/InteractsWithIO.php#L224).

You can directly use the Symfony table, or simply create your word limit (via `Str::limit`) :

```
$size = 20;
$data = [
    ['John', Str::limit('The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Night-Time', $size)],
    ['Rachel', Str::limit('The Catcher in the Rye', $size)]
];

$this->table(['Name', 'Favorite book'], $data);
```

Comment: Thanks, the approach you mentioned in your answer is the one I thought about. The problem is that for big data table it requieres me to iterate over all entries....

Comment: I see. Maybe you can use [`SUBSTRING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) from query